# LINQ selects all items instead of requested from 'where'

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Student objects, containing `Id`, `FirstName` and `LastName`.

I have a list of student Id's of students who are too late. I want to find the names of the students who are too late with a LINQ query.

My code does not return the requested names however. It returns all names of students per number

I can't figure out what's wrong with my linq query.

```
foreach (string studentnumber in pNumbers)
{
    MessageBox.Show(studentnumber);
    int snumber = Int32.Parse(studentnumber);
    //var studentNames = from student in students where student.Id == snumber select new { FirstName = student.FirstName, LastName = student.LastName };
    var studentNames = from student in students where student.Id == snumber select new { FirstName = student.FirstName, LastName = student.LastName };
    foreach (var s in studentNames)
    {
        string name = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName;                        
        presentNamesList.Add(name);
    }
```

Comment: what does `pNumbers` contain? if it contains all the numbers then linq finds one student on each iteration so it displays all the students at the end.

Comment: Why do you select an anonymous object only to concatenate the values? Why not simply select the string in the first place? `select student.FirstName + " " + student.LastName` instead of `select new { FirstName = student.FirstName, LastName = student.LastName }`

Comment: use SelectMany instead of nested foreach loops

Comment: You'd do yourself a great favor if you'd stay stand-by after posting a question so you can respond to comments quickly. Now people lose interest and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I would have done it

```
List<student> students = new List<student>();
students.Add(new student(1,"John","Doe"));
students.Add(new student(2,"Foo","Fighter"));
students.Add(new student(3,"Bob","Builder"));
students.Add(new student(4,"jack","ninja"));

List<int> nothere = new List<int>() { 2, 4 };

var present = students.Where(x => !nothere.Contains(x.studentid)).ToList();
```

the list `present` should now contain the students that are not in the `nothere` list

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
foreach (string studentnumber in pNumbers)
{
    int snumber = Int32.Parse(studentnumber);
    foreach(var s in students.Where(s=>s.Id == snumber))
    { 
       presentNamesList.Add(s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
**One liner**:

```
presentNamesList.AddRange(students.Where(s=>!pNumbers.Contains(s.Id.ToString())).Select(s.Firstname + " " + s.Lastname).Select(s1=>s1.FirstName + " " + s1.LastName).ToList())
```